# using slave thread to wake up a sleeping master thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, interrupt

I would like to define a Timer thread within a Worker thread, that will call the Worker thread's interrupt method if the Worker thread has slept for too long (this sleeping time is defined dynamically). So in essence the code would be as follows:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
    private Timer timer;        
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            timer.start()
            //timer must call this Thread's
            //interrupt method if it sleeps
            //for more than a specified time.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("I was awakened. Gotta work!")
        }

    }
}
```

And this might be the Timer class implemented:

```
public class Timer implements Runnable {


    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            //Interrupt the parent thread it was called from..
            //In this case, an instance of Worker.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

I am not sure I've found a way to achieve this functionality. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have a few inputs,

In the class **Timer** you will need to have an instance of the class **Worker**, so that you can call parent.interrupt().

For doing this I suggest you create a new constructor for the **Timer** class like below,

```
public class Timer implements Runnable {

    Worker parent;

    public Timer(Worker parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            //Interrupt the parent thread it was called from..
            //In this case, an instance of Worker.
            parent.interrupt();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

Secondly, In your **Parent** class you need to change the sequence to the following,

```
timer.start()
Thread.sleep(7000);
```

Otherwise you worker thread will sleep before initiating the timer thread.

I hope it helps..

Comment: I had tried that..., but parent.interrupt() shows as being syntatically correct. Additionally, I added an interrupt() method in the Worker class that calls "thread.interrupt()", to no avail. At any rate, I found a work-around. Thanks for trying regardless.